# Can't figure out what's wrong with my GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

```
 Table `Products`
 ProductId   (INT) PrimaryKey
 Name        (VARCHAR(25))
 Description (VARCHAR(255))

 Table `Images`
 ImageId            (INT) PrimaryKey
 ImagePath          (VARCHAR(255))
 ImageDescription   (VARCHAR(255))
 products_ProductId (INT)
```

The `Images` table contains the images associated to the specific products. It is in a one-to-many relation with the `Products` table, so a Product can have multiple Images. The only column that can be null, (and is in most of the cases as of the moment), is the `Images.ImageDescription`. I would like to select a list of products, and in the same query, get all their images as well. I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT P.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(I.ImagePath, '@', I.ImageDescription) SEPARATOR ',') AS _ProductImages 
FROM (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) as P 
LEFT JOIN Images as I ON I.products_ProductId = P.ProductId
GROUP BY P.ProductId
```

All of the selected products has at least 1 associated row in the Images table, and the first 3 has 3 associated rows in the Images table, yet, when the query runs, and it returns, `_ProductImages` is NULL in every row. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you change your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Can `ImagePath` and/or `ImageDescription` be null in an `Images` record?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I've edited the post, and added the answer to your question. `ImageDescription` can be null, and it is null, in most of the current test cases.

Comment: @Psi `INNER JOIN` produces the same results

Comment: Well, that's a sidenote: Why do you even outer-join when you see it guaranteed that each product has at least one image? To find data inconsistencies?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's possible, that some products won't have an associated image to them. But this wasn't the case in this test scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you concatenate a string with NULL the result is NULL. Hence:

```
CONCAT(I.ImagePath, '@', COALESCE(I.ImageDescription, ''))
```

Comment: yep, this solved it, thanks! will accept it in few minutes:)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Thorsten's answer:

Instead of `CONCAT()` you can also use `CONCAT_WS()`. Read more about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws).

It works well with NULL values and omits needless separators.

Example:

```
mysql > select concat('whatever', '@', NULL);
+-------------------------------+
| concat('whatever', '@', NULL) |
+-------------------------------+
| NULL                          |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql > select concat_ws('@', 'whatever', NULL);
+----------------------------------+
| concat_ws('@', 'whatever', NULL) |
+----------------------------------+
| whatever                         |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql > select concat_ws('@', 'whatever', 'whatever');
+----------------------------------------+
| concat_ws('@', 'whatever', 'whatever') |
+----------------------------------------+
| whatever@whatever                      |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With Thorsten's answer you would get:

```
mysql > select concat('whatever', '@', COALESCE(NULL, ''));
+---------------------------------------------+
| concat('whatever', '@', COALESCE(NULL, '')) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| whatever@                                   |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```